# sign automatic number to my file in bash

Tags: bash, for-loop, scripting

I am trying to assign a unique number to my strings that are redirected and stored in a file.

You have to fill in a form, and I want to send a unique number with it.
example:

```
echo fill in the form

echo place

read place

date

"place: $place, time $(date) >> List
```

It has to look something like this.

```
outcome in List
number 1, place, time
number 2, place, time
number 3, place, time
```

I used a loop but I got the following outcome.

```
number 0, place, time
number 0, place, time.
```

I think I need a function that checks the last number given in the file and add 1 to it, but I wonder if there is an easier way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps this one:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Optionally truncate file
# : > List

I=0

while
    read -p "Place: " PLACE
    read -p "Time: " TIME
    echo "number $((++I)), $PLACE, $TIME" >> List
    read -n 1 -p "Continue? " && [[ $REPLY == [yY] ]]
do
    continue
done
```

Update:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Optionally truncate file
# : > List

shopt -s extglob

for (( I = 1;; ++I )); do
    for (( ;; )); do
        read -p "Place: " PLACE
        read -p "Time: " TIME
        until
            read -p "Save data? "
            [[ $REPLY == [nN]?([oO]) ]]
        do
            [[ $REPLY == [yY]?([eE][sS]) ]] && break 2
            echo "Please answer Y[es] or N[o]."
        done
    done
    echo "Saving \"number $I, $PLACE, $TIME\"."
    echo "number $I, $PLACE, $TIME" >> List
    until
        read -p "Continue? "
        [[ $REPLY == [yY]?([eE][sS]) ]]
    do
        [[ $REPLY == [nN]?([oO]) ]] && break 2
        echo "Please answer Y[es] or N[o]."
    done
    echo
done
```

Comment: Make sure you run it with bash: `bash script.sh`

Comment: I did run it with bash. Ill to figure out what went wrong

Comment: It works now, but the number does not increases. It stays at one.

Comment: It does increase here. You sure you're running it with bash, and that you're not looking at old data in `List`?

Comment: It works now, thank you. I close the script and run it again, the counter starts again. Im trying to avoid that.

Comment: If you want to reset your `List` file's contents everytime you run the script, you can just uncomment `: > List`. I also recommend the newer version as it's less prone to typing mistakes.

Comment: Thank you for providing your code. It still stays at one, but I probally made a mistake since im new to this

Comment: Can you show the output of `bash --version`? Does it make a difference if you do `bash <path name of script>`?

Answer (score 0):

To generate a 16-char random hex string, you can use `r=$(openssl rand -hex 8)`

To find the last number used and increment it, you can do

```
prev=$(awk -F, 'END {print $1}' List)
printf "%d, place:%s, time:%s\n" $((prev+1)) "$place" "$(date)" >> List
```

This is subject to a race condition if the script can be executed simultaneously

To start at 1:

```
if [[ ! -f List ]]; then
    prev=1
else
    prev=$(awk -F, 'END {print $1}' List)
fi
printf "%d, place:%s, time:%s\n" $((prev+1)) "$place" "$(date)" >> List
```

Comment: I want to start at 1. Im a bit confused, I thought printf was csharp.

Comment: printf is a bash builtin: http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-printf

Comment: thank you, I still get one error. -F, : syntax error : Operand expected( error token is ","

Comment: Hmm, should not be an error there. Show exactly what you're executing.

Comment: Any part in particular needs explaining?

Comment: I will try to figure it out by myself first. Printf doesn't seem to create a new line. I tried some of the commands I found online, but my script crashed the moment a second line is printed. What is the best way to create a new line?

Comment: I forgot to add newlines to my printf formats. Fixed

Comment: Sorry to bother you, but can you explain your code to me ? I cant figure it out

Comment: No bother but you didn't answer *my* question. What particular bits don't you get?

Comment: `if [[ ! -f List ]]; then
    prev=1
else
    prev=$(awk -F, 'END {print $1}' List)`  I get what it does in large lines, but I need a detailed explanation

Comment: `Prev=1` will make the list start at two btw. I changed it to 0.